# Linux - What happens to user's running processes when its password is changed?

Tags: linux, process, change-password

On one server I have an application running as a non-root linux user.
I forgot its password, so I was about to change it using root priviledges, but then I wondered if that could harm the application running with that user.

I looked online but I didn't find any answers to this. Does anything happens to the user's running processes when the user's password is changed?

Comment: Have you tried running a second instance (or another dummy application) and try it on there to see what happens?

Comment: No, I don't have the option to do that in this environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

some testing did not cause any problems in a new user, it seems safe to change password without changing any access parameters.

##### Steps:

- Created a new user: testing

```bash
useradd -d /home/testing -m -p testing1 testing
```

- logged into 'testing' user in another terminal.
- launched **htop** (accesses system resources and updates constantly).
- changed password with passwd.
- changed back to the testing terminal and everything was working fine.

Caveat: Havent tested on any software where auth is required (ssh, pc etc...)

Comment: What if the process needs to be restarted? Will it be able to do that?

Comment: A knowledgeable guess would be No, if it needs access to some protected resource. If not, then Im pretty sure the software does not need to store any state and will work the same. It will be as good as a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

The service will keep running, But it won't start the next time.
You will have to reconfigure the service with the new password.